# Gridview not filtering with Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have my gridview that is connected to MYSQL database, before my database crash, the filtering button to Date in my gridview is working. Now I restore my backup database and the filtering button to Date it not working anymore. With same codes and script, is there any other thing to do with restoring databases with regards to privileges? Since I debug my script with breakpoint and it stop here.

```
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=P@$$W0RD");
```

[image: Here is an screenshot]
I already add root users in my SQL. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: yeah, you need the grants and users to be there. `select user,host,password from mysql.user;` might shed some light onto it.

Comment: yes it's there, the user 'root' is present

Comment: great, get your system back in the state it was, with the dbname, all the data, all the users (not root probably), and all the grants

Comment: try to login to your db from terminal using above credentials and check

Comment: go to your mysql directory and then mysql -uroot -p<password> -hlocalhost <DATABASE>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solved it, i added database=bio_db in my script, and now it's connected. But may i know what is the reason for this scenario?

```
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=bio_db;port=3306;username=root;password=P@$$W0RD");
```